# jQuery .on() issue, console.log() works but element interaction doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am using this code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`:

```
$('#flavours').on('click', '.toggle-quantity', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $quantity_percent = $(this).parent().find('.quantity_percent');

    if($quantity_percent.is(':hidden')){
        console.log("is hidden");
        $quantity_percent.show();
    }else{
        console.log("is not hidden");
        $quantity_percent.hide();
    }
});
```

What's happening is the console.log() is working, but the `$quantity_percent` is not showing/hiding.

Additionally, if I add an alert('test') to the beginning of the function (just after `e.preventDefault`) this also doesn't work, but the console.log() continues to work (it correctly logs 'is not hidden').

**EDIT:** Relevant HTML markup:

```
<div id="flavours">

<div class="row flavour" id="flavour_1" style="display: block;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Flavour 1</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label>Flavour Name</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="flavour_name[]" data-flavour-id="1" id="flavour_name_1" class="form-control autocomp" placeholder="Flavour name">
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="flavour_id[]" id="flavour_id_1" class="form-control flavour_id">
                    <p class="flavour_info"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label>Flavour Quantity &nbsp; <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-xs toggle-quantity"><span class="fa fa-filter"></span> <span class="hidden-sm">Switch to </span>drops per ml</a></label>
                    <div class="input-group" id="quantity_percent">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="flavour_percentage_1" name="flavour_percentage[]" placeholder="Flavour Quantity">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group" id="quantity_drops" style="display: none;">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="flavour_drops_1" name="flavour_drops[]" placeholder="Flavour Quantity">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">drops/ml</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="flavour_recommended_percentage"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block remove-flavour"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide relevant HTML markup.

Comment: If the log is working then there's no issue with `on`, it must be something else… please post the relevant html structure or a minimal demo...

Comment: `alert($quantity_percent.length)` What you get? If 0 then its means element doesn't exist

Comment: You could also do a `console.log($quantity_percent)` to see if it can actually find the element.

Comment: *"The console.log() is working"* Which one? Both?

Comment: @Dhaval: `.find()` never returns `undefined`. And even if it was undefined, the code would throw a runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).parent()` is a label element which doesn't have a child with `.quantity_percent`

Also `quantity_percent` is an id and not a class. Use the ID selector

So use

```
var $quantity_percent = $('#quantity_percent');
```

instead of

```
var $quantity_percent = $(this).parent().find('.quantity_percent');
```

Note: IDs must be unique in HTML

EDIT: as per OPs comments

*I updated it to a class rather than ID (as it's on a dynamically growing list)*

Usage

```
var $quantity_percent = $(this).closest('.col-sm-6').find('.quantity_percent');
```

Comment: Also, `quantity_percent` is an id and not a class. Use the `#` selector

Comment: I have changed this now to `var $quantity_percent = $(this).closest('.col-sm-6').find('.quantity_percent');` and it's still not working. I have logged the `$quantity_percent` object and it comes back with: [prevObject: x.fn.x.init[0], context: a.btn.btn-link.btn-xs.toggle-quantity, selector: ".quantity_percent", jquery: "2.0.3", constructor: function…]`

Comment: @a1phanumeric, Use `$('#quantity_percent')`

Comment: Sorry - I'm being a spanner - I updated it to a class rather than ID (as it's on a dynamically growing list) and it works fine now! I'm such a donut at times. Thanks for your help! Would you know why an alert doesn't work at all? (It's not urgent, I just wondered why it doesn't seem to work!).

Answer (score 0):

The `.parent()` targets the `<label>` therefore it can't find `.quantity_percent`

Comment: This looks like a comment. So what's the solution?